# Error on substr(explode)

Tags: php

Do you have any idea what I did wrong in the code row below.
Get an error from my DW editor with no description.

```
$oauth = explode('&',base64_decode($_POST['oauth_token'])); // is ak    
$user_id = substr(explode('=',$oauth['1'])['1'],4); // get error
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array and then you attempt to use a value of this array by indexing directly the value returned by the `explode()` call:

```
explode(...)['1']
```

This improvement of the syntax was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Dreamweaver either doesn't know about it or it thinks (was configured this way?) you use an older PHP version.

Comment: I use PHP v7 but older DW CS6

Comment: Is it free? I guess not. The best PHP tool money can but at the moment is [tag:phpstorm].

Answer (score -1):

try to remove the ' after explode like that :

```
$user_id = substr(explode('=',$oauth['1'])[1],4);
```

Comment: Same result > error stays. Also try with removing other '' or placing '4' without success

Comment: Ok, could you copy paste the error message please ?

Comment: As I wrote there is no error message in DW or in PHP. Only red marked row in DW which normally means code error.

Comment: Hmm, could you printr the $oauth variable here ?